# How to understand the return value within this go closure?

Tags: go, closures

I just wrote the below code and could not understand why n2 is printed as 2. And my understanding is n2 should be printed as 0.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func curryAddTwo(n1 int) (n2 int) {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println(n2) // why it prints 2?
    } ()

    return 2
}

func main()  {
      fmt.Println(curryAddTwo(1))
}

zhuangyan@C02D91SMMD6R ~/coding/go/closure $ ./main
2
2
```

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements -- note that `return 2` is equivalent to `n2 = 2; return` in the last line of `curryAddTwo`. So `n2` has been set to `2` at the time the anonymous closure is called.

Comment: @torek Thanks a lot! And my question was solved.